# Error en la impresión de arreglos en C

Tags: c

estoy empezando a utilizar los arreglos en C y resulta que al guardar palabras en un arreglo e imprimo la palabra del arreglo en la posición 0, aparece la palabra de la posición 0 y 1 pegados entre si, en cambio si imprimo el arreglo de la posición 1 o 2 o 3 etc... no hay ningún problema, se imprime la palabra correcta. ¿Alguna idea de lo que pueda estar pasando?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char palabras[5][12]={"ornitorrinco","mammut","espejo","murcielago"};
    printf("Palabra 1: %s",palabras[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Aparece esto:

```
Palabra1: ornitorrincomammut
```

Y lo que quiero que salga es solo la palabra 1 (o 0), tal que así:

```
Palabra1: ornitorrinco
```

En cambio si cambio la palabra[0] a palabra[1], tal que asi:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char palabras[5][12]={"ornitorrinco","mammut","espejo","murcielago"};
    printf("Palabra 2: %s",palabras[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Aparece esto:

```
Palabra 2: mammut
```

No se concatena la palabra siguiente al arreglo, que es lo que quiero que pase en el ejemplo anterior, ¿alguna idea?
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te muestra `ornitorrincomammut` porqué no dejaste un espacio para el caracter nulo (`\0`).

Si le sumas un +1 al tamaño de columnas de la matriz, te darás cuenta que ahora dará como resultado: `ornitorrinco`.

```
char palabras[5][12 + 1]={"ornitorrinco","mammut","espejo","murcielago"};
```

**¿Por qué dio ese error?**

Como la cadena `ornitorrinco` tiene como longitud 12 caracteres, el compilador no pudo asignarle el caracter nulo, entonces cuando lo vayas a imprimir, saldrá `ornitorrincomammut`.

**¿Por qué no hay problemas con la cadena `mammut`?**

Pues, su longitud es 6 y esto quiere decir, que el compilador si le asigno el caracter nulo, al momento de imprimir, sólo lo hará hasta encontrar el `\0`.